# What is meant by Massif?

Tags: geology, geomorphology, structural-geology

In India, Panchchuli, Kun Nun and Shilong only these mountain are claimed to be massif. Why other mountain formations are not termed as massif...? What are the characteristics of massif..?

Anybody pls explain.

Answer (score 3):

A massif is an undisturbed solid rock mass, which is demarcated by e.g. faults. Massifs keep their internal structure and are displaced as a whole. Only mountains of mountain ranges fulfilling this criteria are called massifs.